# How do I send a HTTP 200 response using Postman

Tags: postman, httpresponse, slack

I created an Slack application that has a modal window to receive information from my users. I use Postman to "interact" with Slack through HTTP requests. Everything is working good, but I'm not being able to close the Slack's modal window. I know I have to send a HTTP 200 to slack when the user clicks in the modal's submit button. Postman is receiving Slack's payload with all user's input information, but now I need to close that modal window. So, how do I respond a HTTP 200 using Postman?

The solution can use Postman's user interface or the function pm.sendRequest(....

Can someone help me sending the HTTP 200 OK using Postman?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Did you found any workaround of how to fix this issue. I am also facing the similar issue, not able to close modal from postman tool

Answer (score 0):

This how I send `GET` request by Postman desktop app.

`Prerequisites`

```js
1. Install Postman
2. API URL // endpoint
3. Live server //localhost needs a server to start the app
```

[image]

@MarceloRohrs let me know the progress